# My variable in Jquery is not working as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, equals

This code is using the Accordion Function only on Smartphones and it works well.

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="accordion" class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
                <h3 class="h3_toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapse1">Titel 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">Content 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
                <h3 class="h3_toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="collapse2">Titel 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">Content 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My JS Code is like this:

```
var auto = $(".h3_toggle").addClass(function (i) {
    return "h3_toggle" + (i + 1);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $(".h3_toggle1").attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapse1").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("aria-controls", "collapse1");
        $("#collapse1").addClass("collapse");
        $("#collapse1").attr("aria-labelledby", "heading1").attr("data-parent", "#accordion");

        $(".h3_toggle2").attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapse2").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("aria-controls", "collapse2");
        $("#collapse2").addClass("collapse");
        $("#collapse2").attr("aria-labelledby", "heading2").attr("data-parent", "#accordion");
    } else {
        $(".h3_toggle1").removeAttr("data-toggle").removeAttr("data-target").removeAttr("aria-expanded").removeAttr("aria-controls");
        $("#collapse1").removeClass("collapse");
        $("#collapse1").removeAttr("aria-labelledby").removeAttr("data-parent");

        $(".h3_toggle2").removeAttr("data-toggle").removeAttr("data-target").removeAttr("aria-expanded").removeAttr("aria-controls");
        $("#collapse2").removeClass("collapse");
        $("#collapse2").removeAttr("aria-labelledby").removeAttr("data-parent");
    }
});
```

This point works well. But I want to to automate my JS Code and write instead this

```
$('.h3_toggle1').attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapse1").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("aria-controls", "collapse1");
```

Write this:

```
$(auto).attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-target", "#collapse1").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("aria-controls", "collapse1");
```

But in this case just the second card will be open, and it doesn't matter, if I click on the header1 over header2.

So what is my Problem?

Comment: What version of BS? Usually you don’t remove “collapse” class and only toggle “show” class. Also, bootstrap probably has its own events for this

Comment: You can pass an object to `.attr()`: `.attr({ "data-target": "foo", "data-toggle": "bar", ...})`

Comment: Look at API methods: `collapse(‘show’)`, `collapse(‘hide’)`, and `collapse(‘toggle’)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that your `auto` variable is holding all `h3_toggle` elements. So when you call `$(auto).attr` you are setting the same attribute to all elements at the same time, in that case both cards will be set with the same target `#collapse1`.

To reduce your code you could make a function like this:

```
function collapse(n) {
  $(".h3_toggle" + n)
    .attr("data-toggle", "collapse")
    .attr("data-target", "#collapse" + n)
    .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
    .attr("aria-controls", "collapse" + n);
  $("#collapse" + n)
    .addClass("collapse")
    .attr("aria-labelledby", "heading" + n)
    .attr("data-parent", "#accordion");
 }
 function expand(n) {
   $(".h3_toggle" + n)
     .removeAttr("data-toggle")
     .removeAttr("data-target")
     .removeAttr("aria-expanded")
     .removeAttr("aria-controls");
   $("#collapse" + n)
     .removeClass("collapse")
     .removeAttr("aria-labelledby")
     .removeAttr("data-parent");
 }
```

And then call it:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
  collapse(1);
  collapse(2);
} else {
  expand(1);
  expand(2);
}
```

Or use a `for` loop

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) collapse(i);
```

Comment: Hey ariel, thank you for your comment. This is what I wanna do. To automize all the "n". But just this code does not still work. I think because of the missing declaration of "n", right? I put :
  for (var n = 0; n <= 2; i++) collapse(n);
to the top and in the end this:
   $(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    collapse(n);
  } else {
    expand(n);
  }

But I think it is wrong cause it doesnt work. Can you help me in this case please?

Comment: without the for loop my cards collapes on smartphone, but they cant expand when i click on the header. My idea was because of the "#heading1", "heading2" in my HTML Markup, right? So I delete the numbers, but then my cards didnt collapse, because of the multiple id's in my HTML Markup? Am confused :D

Comment: ah no it works! sorry. just add in my HTML Markup the number behind my classes h3_toggle. Now I have to automize my HTML markup, thank you a lot ariel!